# Display 'Today' instead of date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I am using angular and moment.js to display dates in my app. If the user chooses a date other than today I want the format to be '12:00 PM Sat 21st Nov' which I have working when the user clicks a day from my calendar with amDateFormat
the following:

```
$scope.setDate = function(day){
    var myDate = day.date;
    $scope.date = moment($scope.date).set(
    {
        'year': myDate.year(), 
        'month': myDate.month(), 
        'date': myDate.date()
    }).toDate();
}

<div> {{ date | amDateFormat:'h:mm A ddd Do MMM'}}</div>
```

If the date chosen is today how do I display the date to be '12:00 PM Today' instead?

Comment: Maybe you could use 'amCalendar' filter instead.
Or you create your own filter for switching between 'amDateFormat' and 'amCalendar'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with angular. However you can use moment calendar for today date.
From the [doc](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/calendar/) you can tweak the calendar like this:

```
moment.locale('en', {
    calendar : {
        sameDay : 'LT [Today]'
    }
});
```

And then call `moment().calendar();`

Here is a snippet with an alternative way of doing it assuming you are using a version that is at least 2.10.5:

```js
 
  
    var divTime = $('#time');
    var time = moment().calendar(null, {
      sameDay: 'LT [Today]'
    });
    divTime.text(time);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="time">
```